# Why does batch referencing non existing column fails outright?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2019

I am trying to understand this weird behavior.

1. This batch selects 1, and then fails, because the table does not exist. That makes sense.

```
SELECT 1;

SELECT  1
FROM NonexistentTable;
```

2. If I was trying to write foolproof script, I could perhaps check the existence of the table first. This selects 1 and finishes without raising any errors. So far so good.

```
SELECT 1;

IF EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
    WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'NonExistentTable'
)
BEGIN
    SELECT 1
    FROM NonExistentTable;
END
```

3. This batch selects 1, and then fails, because the procedure does not exists. That's reasonable.

```
SELECT 1;

EXECUTE sp_nonexisting_procedure;
```

4. This batch refuses to execute outright, which is inconsistent with previously observed scenario. Why?

```
SELECT 1;

SELECT NonexistentColumn
FROM sys.databases;
```

5. It's even more troubling in scripts, where I explicitly try to ascertain the existence of the column.
   Let's create table for the experiment:

```
CREATE TABLE ExistingTable(Id INT, [Name] NVARCHAR(255));
GO
```

And then run this ↓↓↓↓. This fails outright, without even selecting 1 either.

```
SELECT 1;

IF EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
    WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'ExistingTable'
        AND COLUMN_NAME = 'NonexistingColumn'
)
BEGIN
    
    SELECT NonexistingColumn
    FROM ExistingTable;

END
GO
```

Why do existence of columns gets checked right after sending the query, without even trying to execute valid parts of the query first?

What makes it even more puzzling for me is, that tables get checked only when the execution reaches them. (And naively, I would expect tables being more important, therefore getting stricter/earlier checks.)

Comment: Related question, but I don't think it quite explains the inconsistency: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/209220/strange-issue-with-linked-server-and-using-if-exists

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a way to force Deferred Name Resolution even if the table exists when creating a stored procedure?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/13522/is-there-a-way-to-force-deferred-name-resolution-even-if-the-table-exists-when-c)

Comment: Deferred name resolution only works for non-existent objects. If the object exists then the columns must also. Use a separate dynamic SQL scope if you have to, but I question the need for adding columns at runtime in the first place.

Comment: @Charlieface: I don't think that's an answer, but it is definitely helpful reading.  "_I question the need for adding columns at runtime in the first place._" Well, I've encountered this at opposite scenario - when we removed certain unused column and one procedure actually referenced it. (Well, it inserted NULL in it.) But before this, there was a some logic, that could happen without issues. (Or so I thought.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why do existence of columns gets checked right after sending the query, without even trying to execute valid parts of the query first?

For reference, what you're asking about is the difference between a runtime error and a compile / parse time error. Column existence checks are happening at compile / parse time here.

> What makes it even more puzzling for me is, that tables get checked only when the execution reaches them.

My guess for one reason why non-existent tables aren't checked until runtime is because it's valid in T-SQL to specify and reference a temp table that doesn't exist yet, in certain contexts, for example within a procedure. This is because temp tables are scoped to the session that creates them, and therefore may not exist at compile time, but can be created at runtime by another source, e.g. another parent procedure that calls the child procedure which references said temp table.